# How to merge different magento installed websites to one installation as multiple store

Tags: multistore, multidomain

I have 4 different magento websites domain1.com, domain2.com, domain3.com, domain4.com with different installation having different themes, catlog , etc.
Now need to merge all 4 installations with having same theme, catalog, CMS pages/block they have to one installation to domain1.com as a multiple stores with multi domain
What is the best way to do that?
Thanks in advance for help

Comment: How did you achieve this? How did transferred customers and orders for different stores?

Answer (score 0):

That's tricky question:) I suppose that you will use same tax rate etc... So you needto create one website, than 4 stores, and for each store you need one store view. If tou eill have multiple language then you create more storeviews under each store.

But then you need to set correct store code on server level (ngnix or apache) so that you will root correctly on the stores. And you need to be carefulabout configuration on base url..

I hope that this is helpful for you.

Bit still everything depends on logic/architecture which you want to achieve.

I almoust forgot about default categories... For each store you need to create default category and link it to the right store.